# Linux test hardware ie hdmi

Tags: php, linux, bash

Firstly I apologise for the lack on information in this question. All I have really been able to do towards this is simply search and attempt to find info.

Basically I have a STB that is based on linux. The box has a HDMI and AV port, Using PHP/Bash or any other suggested method (I am happy to try anything), I need to test which port is being used and if no port is being used I can issue a halt command. So what I need is if someone can tell me within linux how I can test hardware, i.e test the hdmi port to see if any signal is being sent etc.

Comment: look here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177176

Comment: could you update the question with the output of `xrandr | grep connected`?